# Is deleting random node from a heap possible?

Tags: data-structures, heap

I have a situation where I want to delete a random node from the heap, what choices do I have?  I know we can easily delete the last node and the first node of the heap. However if we say delete the last node, then I am not sure if the behavior is correctly defined for deleting a random node from the heap.

e.g.

```
_______________________
|X|12|13|14|18|20|21|22|
------------------------
```

So in this case I can delete the node 12 and 22, this is defined, but can I for example delete a random node, e.g. say 13, and still somehow maintain the complete tree property of the heap (along with other properties)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're describing a binary heap maintained in an array, with the invariant that `A[N] <= A[N*2]` and `A[N] <= A[N*2 + 1]` (a min-heap).

If yes, then the approach to deletion is straightforward: replace the deleted element with the last element, and perform a sift-down to ensure that it ends up in the proper place. And, of course, decrement the variable that holds the total number of entries in the heap.

Incidentally, if you're working through heap examples, I find it better to use examples that do not have a total ordering. There's nothing in the definition of a heap that requires (eg) `A[3] <= A[5]`, and it's easy to get misled if your examples have such an ordering.

Comment: Random deletion in array-based-heap is very inefficient operation. You may need to search the whole array to find out the position of random number. Am I right ?

Comment: @KaushikLele - you wouldn't search for the position of a random number (which may not even be in the heap).  Instead you would choose a random position and remove the corresponding entry (in a way that preserves a heap).

Answer (score 0):

I don't this think it is possible to remove random element from a heap. Let's take this example (following same convention):

`3, 10, 4, 15, 20, 6, 5.`

Now if I delete element 15, the heap becomes: `3, 10, 4, 5, 20, 6`

This makes heap inconsistent because of `5` being child of `10`.

The reason I think random deletion won't work is because you may substitute an inside node (instead of root or a leaf) in the heap, and thus there are two paths (parents and children) to `heapify` (as compared to `1` path in case of `pop()` or `insert()`).
Please let me know in case I am missing something here.

Comment: According to your argument, you should not be able to remove the top element from the heap either.  The top element also has two children.  I think you are missing the significance of the "sift down" step in Anon's answer.

Comment: I think I got what I was missing here. The number which is replaced might have to be "silt down" or "silt up" as needed (eg: insert() follows a silt up and delete() follows a silt down). Is that correct?